# Does libstdc++ comply with MISRA C++?

Tags: c++, standards, libstdc++, standards-compliance, misra

This is motivated by a question that I made previously (on the same topic):

[Do BLAS and LAPACK libraries comply with MISRA standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985186/do-blas-and-lapack-libraries-comply-with-misra-standard)

Now I have a much more important question: is **libstdc++** (which is the implementation of the standard library by gcc) MISRA C++:2008 compliant? I assume the answer is **yes**... as long as you compile your code with `gcc` and the `-std=c++03` flag.

What happens if I compile the code with the standard from 2011 (i.e. `-std=c++11`)? Is that MISRA C++:2008 compliant? Do I have to prove that the libstdc++ is MISRA compliant? I can write deviations for a couple of rules (for example, I want to use `std::array` instead of C-style arrays), but writing them for the whole MISRA standard looks like a terryfying task.

I would appreciate any insight into this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not MISRA-C++ compliant. Neither is glibc. But then there's no requirement from the standard that the library must be written in a certain language either. Standard compliance for the standard library itself is a rather muddy topic, with or without MISRA.

I very much doubt that MISRA-C++ is a priority for these libraries. The library (and gcc) maintainers are mostly from the Linux/Desktop ("hosted system") side of things, where MISRA compliance isn't required.

If you need a MISRA compliant standard library, you'll have to look at the various commercial embedded systems compilers.

> What happens if I compile the code with the standard from 2011? Is that MISRA C++:2008 compliant?

No it is not compliant. MISRA-C++ requires explicitly that you use C++03, so it will be very hard to justify a deviation here.

> Do I have to prove that the libstdc++ is MISRA compliant?

There is no way to prove it, since it is not.

Comment: Overall, if you need a safe subset for C++11 and beyond, [CERT C++](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=88046682) might be a better choice since that's more aimed towards desktop/system programming and less towards mission-critical embedded systems (where C++ isn't suitable in the first place). They appear to be updated to C++14.

Comment: You are so right here. I am building my project in my laptop, and hence I am using "desktop" compilers (g++, clang++). However, since the final goal is to deploy in embedded devices, I should definitely think about embedded system compilers. Thank you very much!

Comment: @enanone Then you should probably check with the big compiler vendors like IAR, Green Hills, Keil etc if they support it. If not, I'm pretty sure some of the automotive semiconductor companies have compilers like that, but then you are limited to using certain processor families.

Comment: I also found these [guidelines from AUTOSAR](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/.../standards/.../AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf) which look very much on-topic here. They address MISRA-C++ and C++14 both. I haven't read the document.

Comment: There is much that could be done to the Standard Library, to remove behaviours that result in the need for the appropriate MISRA C/C++ rules... but as we know, the two WGs are more intent in adding more new features to the language, than fixing problems in the existing

Comment: @Andrew Well... I don't know what the C++ WG started smoking in 2011, but apart from that they are at least not afraid to fix blatantly obvious problems in the language (logical operators give bool not int, string literals are const char[] not char[], i=i++ could as well be well-defined etc etc). While the C WG is extremely orthodox and treat language bugs as cherished old pets.

Comment: Other than wishing to deprecate the term "bug" (they're errors and omissions), you get a +1 for the chuckle :-)